# Convert byte array to object

Tags: c#

Is there a way in C# to convert a plain byte array to an object?

e.g given this class:

```
class Data
{
    public int _int1;
    public int _int2;
    public short _short1;
    public long _long1;
}
```

I want to basically be able to do something like this:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
var obj = (Data)bytes;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There must be some login in the relation between your bytes and the instance that you would like to create.

Comment: Technically, you can implement an *operator*, i.e. `public static explicit operator Data(Byte[] source) {...}` but *serialization* is much better solution.

Comment: Get some idea - [See here](http://www.morgantechspace.com/2013/08/convert-object-to-byte-array-and-vice.html)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to read data written from some C/C++ structs. Is that the case?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I know I can use BitConverter to convert each member separately, I can't deserialize as the data wasn't serialized to start with, it's just the raw data. It can be done in C++, just to say I know this block of data is really this structure, treat it as this, but maybe you can't do this easily in C#.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try marshalling:

Declare the layout of your class as Sequential (and note that you will need to use `Pack = 1`):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class Data
{
    public int _int1;
    public int _int2;
    public short _short1;
    public long _long1;
}
```

Marshal the bytes into a new instance of the Data class:

```
var bytes = new byte[] { 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
var data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
gcHandle.Free();

// Now data should contain the correct values.

Console.WriteLine(data._int1);    // Prints 1
Console.WriteLine(data._int2);    // Prints 2
Console.WriteLine(data._short1);  // Prints 3
Console.WriteLine(data._long1);   // Prints 4
```

For convenience you could write a static method on Data to do the conversion:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class Data
{
    public int _int1;
    public int _int2;
    public short _short1;
    public long _long1;

    public static Data FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
        gcHandle.Free();
        return data;
    }
}

...

var data = Data.FromBytes(new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0});
```

If you really wanted to you could write an explicit operator to convert from an array of bytes, to get the syntax in your OP. I would suggest just using `Data.FromBytes()` which is going to be a lot clearer IMO.

Still, just for completeness:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
class Data
{
    public int _int1;
    public int _int2;
    public short _short1;
    public long _long1;

    public static explicit operator Data(byte[] bytes)
    { 
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var data = (Data)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
        gcHandle.Free();
        return data;
    }
}

...

var data = (Data)new byte[] {1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
```

Comment: Thanks, I think given what I'm trying to do, this is the best answer.

Comment: What about systems with big endian?

Comment: @Geograph You'd have to make sure the bytes were the right way around. (OP is after the same effect as a C++ cast.)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`BitConverter.ToInt32/Int16/Int64`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) methods. You have only have to specify the starting index like:

```
Data data = new Data();
data._int1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
data._int2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 4);
data._short1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 8);
data._long1 = BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes,10);
```

Just remember:

[BitConverter.ToInt32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the
>   computer system's architecture;

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to convert a byte array into an object.

```
var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    object obj = binaryFormatter.Deserialize(ms);
    return (Data)obj;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that will do the conversion in one go.

But you can build on top of [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
var d = new Data();
var sI32 = sizeof(Int32);
d._int1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
d._int2 = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, sI32);
d._short1 = BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, 2*sI32);
…
```