# How can i convert byteArray to object from SerialPort

Tags: c#, object, binary, serial-port

I have input COM ports. I receive data from these like `binary`. Problem is i can't convert `binary` to `object`.

I try this.

```
    private void dataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dataLength = _serialPort.BytesToRead;
        var data = new byte[dataLength];
        int nbrData = _serialPort.Read(data, 0, dataLength);
        var Data = _serialPort.Encoding.GetString(data);
    }
    public object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
    {
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(arrBytes))
        {
            object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }
```

It throw exception this line `object obj = bf.Deserialize(ms);`

`System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 02-02-CC-CC-33-33-53-40-33-33-83-40-66-66-A6-40-9A`

How can solve this? Answers will be evaluated.

### EDIT

I have Ardunio System. Ardunio send data like `binary` format on `SerialPort`. This data actually is `object`. Object like this.

```
typedef struct MainCompPacket {
    uint8_t status;
    uint8_t sensorStatus;
    float pressure;  // mb
    float accX;      // g
    float accY;      // g
    float accZ;      // g
    float gyroX;     // deg/s
    float gyroY;     // deg/s
    float gyroZ;     // deg/s
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
} MainCompPacket;
```

I should get data in WPF app. I can't because this data is `binary` format. I can't intervention Ardunio system. If i can, i change with sending `json` format.

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing or why you're doing it. What kind of device are you using? Adding the make and model may also be beneficial. While C# is case-sensitive and allows one to create variables such as `data` and `Data`, if you have a list of bad ideas, you should add this to it. If you don't have a list of bad ideas, create one, and add this to it.

Comment: Does it make sense to send objects over the serial port? A lot of the information seems irrelevant because the memory space changes. Wouldn't it be better to extract and send only the essence of the data you want to send?

Comment: Unfortunately, your post doesn't make sense, hence my comment.  Apparently, what you've tried isn't working which is why you're posting here. I suggest you take a step back and describe the device your working with, what kind of data it's generating, and what you'd like to do with the data. If you haven't already done so, read all of the documentation for [SerialPort Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0). If you click on my username, and in the search box append the word `serial-port` you'll find some posts that may be helpful.

Comment: `MainCompPacket` isn't sending any data. The part you want to look at is the part that is sending the data. It seems that you need to perform more research to understand how your unidentified Ardunio device works (ie: communicates).

Comment: @user09938 Actually `MainCompPacket` data type in c++. This is data format. i checked connection pack and i can see binary pack.

Comment: I don’t think you can deserialize any old binary data with the BinaryFormatter class. It appears that class deals with a specific data format, and your incoming data doesn’t conform. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33736953/convert-byte-array-to-object

Comment: It would be a mistake to assume that the binary formats of each object are compatible, even though the CPU architecture, OS, programming language, compiler, etc. are all different. It will be necessary to convert them into text data such as JSON or CSV, add markers such as STX, ETX, etc., send them, and identify and convert them on the receiving side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @padeso said. Binary format need scheme for converting  to object.

Firstly i create struct c# side. same data scheme in binary.
Second i create static method for converting process.
Finally i used Marshal and converting binary to objects

```
public struct MainCompPacket 
{
    byte status;
    byte sensorStatus;
    float pressure;  // mb
    float accX;      // g
    float accY;      // g
    float accZ;      // g
    float gyroX;     // deg/s
    float gyroY;     // deg/s
    float gyroZ;     // deg/s
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public static MainCompPacket FromBytes(byte[] bytes)
    {
        GCHandle gcHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
        var data = (MainCompPacket)Marshal.PtrToStructure(gcHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(Data));
        gcHandle.Free();
        return data;
    }
}
```